Where was director Tommy Wiseau born and/or raised?
Can anyone find some definitive information about where Tommy Wiseau (director of the "movie" THE ROOM) is from and/or his age?
Please do not just link to his Wikipedia page. That does not help. A "hack" out of nowhere who claims to be from Transylvania, with not much info surrounding him, nonetheless completed a $6,000,000 film shot both on HD and film. 
How do we NOT know more about this guy?

The wiki page claims he started a clothing company, leveraged its earnings to move into retail real estate, and used the profits for that to fund his movie. Is there a specific reason you think that this doesn't add up? It's mostly unverified, that's true, but it isn't downright implausible.

Are you asking for biographical data? Or are you asking how this hack/weirdo came up with $6 million? The wording makes this kinda sound like a rant.

Seems like a question that should be able to be answered in a few words. Not a whole book I need to decode. Where is he from?

"Seems like a question that should be able to be answered in a few words." - The reactions to the question suggest that it isn't, though (or at least isn't worded as such).

Sure, he's from either: Poland, Hungary, Romania, Bulgaria, Czechoslovakia, Armenia, Azerbaijan, Belarus, Estonia, Georgia, Kazakhstan, Kyrgyzstan, Latvia, Lithuania, Moldova, Russia, Tajikistan, Turkmenistan, Ukraine or Uzbekistan. GOOD LUCK ;)

@JohnSmithOptional I agree that identify-this-actor is not really fitting in itself, but director is an awful tag, the question is not about the job of a director at all.

I couldn't find a "Is this dude from Mars?" tag.

I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is asking about the private life of a person who just happens to be in the film world. It is not about Movies & TV directly and should be closed.

Agreed its not about Movies or TV directly.

Since there is going to be a movie about him (The Disaster Artist) this might still be useful info.

Wow! Someone on Reddit has apparently done all the research! 
A Redditor sleuth has unraveled the mystery of Tommy Wiseau's nationality
From the original full post: "I believe Tommy is Polish." 
This guy hunted down clues from The Disaster Artist, including Tommy's "uncle Stanley and his aunt Katherine" from New Orleans and found their obituaries. Their last name was Wieczor, fairly close to Wiseau.

Being Polish would also match with several other points from the book: 1. Tommy is apparently from an Eastern Bloc country 2. He is Roman Catholic, Poland 96.12% Catholic 3. First left his country to go to Berlin. Warsaw is close to Berlin and accessible by rail, most likely the first stop for a Pole traveling west.

This is all pretty convincing and seems beyond mere speculation. I am satisfied.

I really never planned to answer one of my own questions, but as this seems correct, and I suspect John Smith Optional (at least) will be interested in this new information, I had to do it..

Good find! Someone else's curiosity was obviously piqued as much as mine after reading the Book! I'm still waiting for further confirmation, as this is still pretty speculative... but a plausible, well reasoned conclusion nontheless.

WE DO.
Greg Sestero's Book, published earlier this year, tells Johnny's story through parable. 

The story is revealed through a recollection of a story Johnny apparently told Greg whilst they lived together, during the years they were both supporting each other.
Because Greg is able to filter the tale through the of I'm-Stitching-Different-Bits-Of-The-Stories-He's-Told-Me lens, it's implied the story may have been slightly embellished to support the essence of the story.
The 'hero' of the story is simply referred to as T_____, and later 'Thomas' however, and given the context of the book there is no way this isn't intended to be Tommy's life story, its simply some legal footwork and interesting storytelling.
It certainly explains his accent, origin, name and speculates on his wealth with credible ballast.
It's 'implied' that T___ came from an undisclosed former Soviet Bloc country, where he was greatly impoverished. He was beaten as a child, possibly due to him being considered in some way deficient or lacking in behavioral faculties.
This only galvanized his passion to escape from his environment, and he quickly focused on America as being the most salient alternative, in respect of the fact it was considered the total opposite of Soviet Europe: this was clearly during the early stages of the Cold War, which helps with placing when this happened.
Eventually, he was able to secure a 'way' into France, for him and a cousin. This is where Tommy was able to create a new identity for himself, and started learning the French Language.
T___ and his cousin acquired work, illegally, cleaning a restaurant; sleeping on the concrete floor of the basement and stealing food to survive. 

T___ 's cousin was caught by the authorities, apparently after the management supplied/co-operated with his extradition back to his original country. It is unclear why T___ wasn't taken too, but Wisseau apparently claims that the character was 'popular with ladies'. 
Having seen Tommy Wisseau, I hope this was part was a piece of the story's 'Embellishment'; or there is no god.


'He Looks like a rotting pig' - My Girlfriend.

Tommy was beaten and attacked by various authorities, as the harassment of illegal immigrants was considered 'sport' in the part of France T____ was staying. It is implied he may have had to perform sexual favors for members of both gender at this point, albeit to 'survive' instead of as a sexual preference.
However, earlier in the book, attention is drawn to the fact that the first night Greg Sestero spent in Tommy's flat,he was possibly goaded with chicken calls (Chieep! !Chieepchiepe!) for not joining Tommy in bed. Sestero dismisses this as 'just Tommy being Tommy', as though it could have been a joke, but its interesting it's mentioned. It leaves a certain ambiguity to the orientation of his sexuality.   
Eventually, T___ receives sponsorship from an American, Drew Caffrey.
Now this figure is quite mysterious,and his motives are never fully revealed, but he eventually was given a production credit for his financial contribution to the project and a casting credit for the Movie, despite the fact he was dead. It is unknown why he played his role in bringing T____ to America, but its ultimately irrelevant. 
After moving to America, T____ fully embraced his new American Identity, becoming fiercely patriotic of his adoptive homeland and deliberately evasive over his personal history.
He becomes xenophobic towards any European Country, as a protection mechanism against speculation to his background. It isn't very convincing. 
After a brief foray into education, he moves to San Francisco. The vibrant atmosphere and social scene are cited as luring him there, so this could be the late 1960's and early 1970's.  
Once he arrives, he gets a job selling model bird 'boomerangs' on the pier; T____ is remarkably adept at piloting and demonstrating these birds, and quickly gains local fame for his incredible skill and showmanship.
T____ adopts the name 'Thomas' to sound more American, and (in a rare moment of deference to his immigrant status) decides on the foreign surname 'Wiseau'.
This is a corruption of the French word 'Oiseau', meaning Bird.
Tommy Wiseau = Thomas the Bird Man
Eventually, Thomas realizes that he is the functional component of the operation, and ceases to become and Vendor by acquiring supplies directly, and becoming a business owner.
He establishes strong links with Chinese Toy Companies, whom make cheap street vendor nick-nacs and souvenirs. These links strengthen, possibly because Tommy Wiseau is genuinely an incredibly shrewd businessman. 
He moves into Yo-yo sales, Pleather jackets, and eventually into retail.
Over time his business expands and he takes over various premises, forming an empire called 'Street Fashions USA', of which he creates his own commercials. 
Later in his life, he is discussing his mutual love of actors and cinema with Drew Caffrey, and somehow Tommy is inspired to pursue this as a career. 
He attends acting classes, and is subsequently ridiculed, for his captivating, clueless performances. He believes himself to be channeling the 'Passion' of James Dean and Marlon Brando, but is widely received as just being totally, balls off the wall insane by his audience.
Greg presents himself as being charmed by this character, and chooses to work with him 'for the experience'. 
Eventually the two support each other, Wiseau eventually allowing Greg Sestero to move into one of his apartments in LA, for very little rent.
It becomes clear that Tommy is trying to piggy back on Greg's success, especially Greg's role in Retro Puppet Master.
The rest, as they say....

If you want to know how all this ties into The Room, you'll honestly just have to read the book.
I've done a huge information dump here, but there's SO MUCH MORE in the book, this is barely skimming.

Nobody knows, as Tommy has deliberately obscured his past so no-one can legally trace him. 
In The Disaster Artist, Greg Sestero's book about the background and making of The Room, a story about an Eastern European immigrant to America is told through parable, but its function is to be interpreted as Tommy Wiseau's life story. This is merely a device to avoid certain litigious ramifications of publication.
In this story, the immigrant boy is sponsored to move to America by an American named Drew Caffrey, of whom little research/journalism has been conducted.
The immigrant boy forsakes his previous identity, enjoying his legal privilege of privacy to retroactively remove any trace of his original identity and refusing to acknowledge he was from anywhere other than New Orleans. 
Drew Caffrey, his only link to his pre-American identity, is dead. The truth probably died with him, unless Wiseau makes some kind of public confession, undoing all the work he's achieved since immigration. 
[Little experiment: See which answer gets the most votes]

I had to +1 it on principal, now didn't I? As experiments go, to be a valid test the answers would have had to go live at the same time, not a day apart. Still. I like the spirit.

now we've just got to bring this to people's attention somehow, to find out whether the site prefers brevity or extrapolation!

Specifically to a question with no known answer? This Q is not indicative of most questions here.

Seriously, thanks for both answers. Comedy and exaggeration don't always come across through text, so hopefully you don't think I was being mean or angry or even offended. I was a bit flabbergasted by such a long answer, but I read the HELL out of it and enjoyed it. As for answering, well, yeah. I just want to know where this dude came from to make sure I never go there! ;)

THE WORST IS SEEING HIS LUMPY ASS EVERY TIME I HAVE TO SCROLL THROUGH! "He looks like 'Rambo' from UHF!" -RiffTrax

Nah, I get the spirit of debate, and it played out towards answers, so yey! Just out of curiosity, where do you think he comes from? maybe there's a stack where you could ask a linguist for their interpretation? he's certainly not American, and doesn't actually speak French?

You couldn't resist making it longer... hahahaha

@MeatTrademark only at Christian's request! :) 'the second answer could surely use at least some of the information from the first answer'.. I'm trying to keep this as collaborative as possible, and he gives good advice!

I've opened this, hoping some linguist might be able to weigh in...

@MeatTrademark If you ask an outsider, the second one is definitely the better one for me. (and I guess your comment was a quote from The Room? Man, I definitely got to watch this thing after all those discussions).

I picked this as a shorter answer with the same outcome. Thanks, John, for the ride. You sill get points and I don't.

This would probably be better suited as a comment, but one cannot put images there. So, here... a recent XKCD comic explains it all:

The mouse-over text:

'Why on Earth would someone commit air piracy just to finance a terrible movie decades later?'
'People are very strange these days.'

